# In Highcharts x-axis -how to set tickmark for unequal numerical (not datetime) data

Tags: jquery, highcharts

In Highcharts x-axis - how can I set the tick marks for unequal numerical (not datetime) data? I require tick marks exactly above the x-label value. 
My x-axis category data is (15,25,50,75,85,100), so the tick marks are not pointed above my x-axis label.

Answer (score 3):

You can use xAxis.tickPositioner function for manually positioning your ticks so it will meet your requirements.

Here you can find code that help you with your issue:

```
xAxis: {
  tickPositioner: function() {
    var tickPositions = [];
    Highcharts.each(this.series[0].options.data, function(p) {
      tickPositions.push(p[0]);
    });
    return tickPositions;
  }
},
```

And here you can see an example how it can work: http://jsfiddle.net/fww89gpt/